# Correlation in SPSS. But I don't understand about some argument of correlation in spss

Tags: spss

```
                CORRELATIONS
              /VARIABLES=temperature heartrate
              /MISSING=PAIRWISE
               /PRINT=TWOTAIL NOSIG.
```

## here temperatue and heartrate are two variables.

## here what is the meaning of nosig , listwise, include, exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look these up in the Command Syntax Reference available via help or use the dialog box interface at Analyze > Correlate > Bivariate